# No buildroot login in QEMU

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, qemu, buildroot

I downloaded buildroot-2019.05 source code from the website and executed the following steps:

```
$ make qemu_x86_64_defconfig
$ make -j8
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -M pc -kernel output/images/bzImage -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw -append "root=/dev/vda console=ttyS0" -net nic,model=virtio -net user -nographic
```

I get the kernel logs on the terminal,

```
Starting network: udhcpc: started, v1.30.1
random: mktemp: uninitialized urandom read (6 bytes read)
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending select for 10.0.2.15
udhcpc: lease of 10.0.2.15 obtained, lease time 86400
deleting routers
random: mktemp: uninitialized urandom read (6 bytes read)
adding dns 10.0.2.3
OK
```

But i don't get buildroot login.

When i run the following command

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -M pc -kernel output/images/bzImage -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw -append "root=/dev/vda" -net nic,model=virtio -net user
```

I get QEMU terminal and also the login screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference I've noticed is lack of "console=ttyS0" in the second invocation. I guess that the buildroot didn't run "getty" or similar program on /dev/ttyS0 but run it on /dev/tty1, and that is why you can login in the second case but not the first one. It is also possible that you are not connected the qemu to ttyS0 in your guest linux.

Comment: What do you mean by not connected the qemu to ttyS0?

Comment: It means that ttyS0 from guest Linux is redirected to qemu. So every information which Linux guest sends to ttyS0 will appear in qemu screen.

Comment: make menuconfig -> System Configuration -> Run a getty and replaced with ttyS0, it solved the issue